# Send local notification when download completes through NSURLSession / NSURLSessionDownloadTask

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am using `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` objects on an `NSURLSession` to allow users to download documents while the app is in the background / device locked. I also want to inform the user that individual downloads have finished through a local notification.

To that end, I am triggering a local notification in the `-URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:` download task delegate method, however I am wondering if there might be a better place to add the code triggering a notification, since the way Apple explains it, the download task will be passed to the system, and from that I am deriving that those delegates will not be called anymore on the download task's delegate once (or shortly after) the app is backgrounded.

**My question:** What is the best place to add the code for triggering the local notifications? Has anybody had any previous experience in adding this sort of a functionality to their application?

Comment: Some things I am noticing from experimenting with this:

When multiple files are queued up to be downloaded the notifications are either coalesced and sent at the end of all downloads or not all of them are triggered.

I have also experimented with adding the notification trigger code in `-application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:` but that *seems* (from the tests I've done so far) to only trigger the notification once, not for each document that has been downloaded.

Answer (score 9):

Answer on your question can be found in Apple documentation [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html):

> In iOS, when a background transfer completes or requires credentials,
>   if your app is no longer running, iOS automatically relaunches your
>   app in the background and calls the
>   `application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:`
>   method on your app’s `UIApplicationDelegate` object. This call provides
>   the identifier of the session that caused your app to be launched.
>   Your app should store that completion handler, create a background
>   configuration object with the same identifier, and create a session
>   with that configuration object. The new session is automatically
>   reassociated with ongoing background activity. Later, when the session
>   finishes the last background download task, it sends the session
>   delegate a `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:` message.
>   Your session delegate should then call the stored completion handler.
>
> If any task completed while your app was suspended, the delegate’s
>   `URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:` method is then
>   called with the task and the URL for the newly downloaded file
>   associated with it.

As you see it's much more complicated then just set `delegate` object. By delegate methods you will be notified only if app in foreground mode. In other cases (app in background mode, app is terminated) you need handle `AppDelegate` methods that are described in above quote.

Also Apple provides [example project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleBackgroundTransfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013416), that shows how to work with background download/upload tasks. This example will help you to find place where to put "Local Notification" code.

Comment: Even though the documentation says that `application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler` is called every time a task completes, I have found that this is not the case, it is actually called once when the whole session finishes. Any ideas regarding this?

Comment: @Andrei It doesn't say that it called every time when task is completed. It says that this method will be called if **app was terminated** when task is completed. Probably app was in background when all other tasks are completed. In this case this method will be called only once.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Any idea how I should go about finding out when **one task was finished**?

Comment: @Andrei, as I understand you need handle this call `application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler` if task completed when app was terminated. In all other cases you need handle `NSURLSession` delegate methods. Also all logic described in Apple documentation has to be implemented in your app.

Answer (score 0):

As Visput explained above, this method will be called once the download completes.`application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:`

This will happen if you use the ***NSURLSessionConfiguration*** class with the ***backgroundSessionConfiguraton***. You might be missing that piece.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"com.BGTransfer"];
sessionConfiguration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 5; // To set the max concurrent connections
```

It is explained in detail [here](https://www.appcoda.com/background-transfer-service-ios7/).

Answer (score -1):

As Suggested by @Gautam Jain u have to use `backgroundSessionConfiguration` to achieve ur objective.Below i have attached a example ,hope it helps you

**DownloadModel.h**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface DownloadModel : NSObject<NSURLSessionDelegate,NSURLSessionTaskDelegate,NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate>{
NSString *resp;
}

+(instancetype)shared;
-(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *) downloadTaskWithURL:(NSURL*)url ;
@end
```

**DownloadModel.m**

```
#import "DownloadModel.h"
@interface DownloadModel ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSURLSession *downloadSession;
@end

@implementation DownloadModel
+(instancetype)shared{
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
static DownloadModel *downloader=nil;

dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

    downloader=[DownloadModel new];
});

return downloader;

}

-(id)init{
self=[super init];
if(self){

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *downloadConfig=[NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"DownloadDemo"];
    //        downloadConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30;
    //        downloadConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30;
    //        downloadConfig.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
    //        downloadConfig.sessionSendsLaunchEvents=YES;
    downloadConfig.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
    downloadConfig.networkServiceType = NSURLNetworkServiceTypeBackground;
    //        downloadConfig.discretionary = YES;
    self.downloadSession=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:downloadConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    self.downloadSession.sessionDescription=@"Video Downloader";

}

return self;
}

-(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *) downloadTaskWithURL:(NSURL*)url{
return [self.downloadSession downloadTaskWithURL:url];
}

#pragma mark download delegate
```

## use notification OR Local Notification in this method

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL(NSURL *)location{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DownloadFinish" object:downloadTask userInfo:nil];
}
```

## For Progress of Download

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite{

CGFloat progress=(CGFloat)totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpectedToWrite;

NSDictionary *userInfo=@{@"progress":@(progress)};

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DownloadProgress" object:downloadTask userInfo:userInfo];


}



#pragma mark delegate
-(void)URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSURLSession *)session{
AppDelegate *appdelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if(appdelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler){
    appdelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler();
    appdelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler=nil;
}
}
@end
```

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (copy ,nonatomic) void(^backgroundSessionCompletionHandler)();

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSString *)identifier completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler{

self.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler=completionHandler;

[DownloadModel shared];
}
```

**ViewController.m Call this Method `-(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *) downloadTaskWithURL:(NSURL*)url`**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 

//Add Notification observers to track download progress and call the above method

[DownloadModel shared] downloadTaskWithURL:url];

}
```

**Don't Forget to enable Background Fetch**[image]

Comment: You don't need to add "Background Fetch" for background downloading.